# How to get SKU Number

Tags: app-store

What is a SKU Number and how do I get my application one for the appstore?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

[SKU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock-keeping_unit) is short for **Stock Keeping Unit**.

It's a number you personally make up, which you yourself can use for keeping track of your applications. You can think of it as a product ID.

Source: [What SKU Number to use when submitting apps?](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html)

Comment: Unfortunately Renato's link is now broken as well.

Answer (score 29):

Might be answer is late but look at Simple Information of **[SKU *(Stock keeping unit)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock-keeping_unit)** number is, it's an unique tracking number *(an arbi­trary num­ber)* that are used in appStore for your application. You can put what­ever you want in there as long as it is unique among your appli­ca­tions. Try to fol­low a pat­tern for the SKU Num­ber of your apps so that you will be able to bet­ter orga­nize them. I sug­gest a com­bi­na­tion of the cur­rent ***`year + month + ID`*** for your app. So if you’re devel­op­ing your first appli­ca­tion on **september 1991** *(oh,, yah it's my b'day's month and year :D )*, you could put your SKU Num­ber as ***`“19910901”`***. Here, I am just suggesting you for this pattern but you can take/choose any pattern which easy for you.

Answer (score 4):

Since there are already a couple answers on what it is, here's where to find it

[image: App Store Connect | App Information | SKU]